# can't login to wordpress admin - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't log in my wordpress admin. This is the error that I get when I got to
mydomain.com/login

> Warning: Use of undefined constant ETHEME_BASE_URL - assumed
> 'ETHEME_BASE_URL' (this will throw an Error in a future version of
> PHP) in
> /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/et-core-plugin/app/models/customizer/theme-options/global/global.php
> on line 138
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/et-core-plugin/app/models/customizer/theme-options/global/global.php:138)
> in
> /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php
> on line 1416

Comment: Contact the developer of the plugin that you're using

Comment: The warning likely causes the header error. Disabling error displaying would likely resolve that.. not sure what the constant is used for though or if it is needed. Shouldn't display errors in production anyway though; log the errors and monitor your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The et-core-plugin is likely incomaptible with your version of PHP.
Check if there is an update to that plugin.

Alternatively you might get away with changing the error_reporting level.
e.g. by adding `ini_set('ERROR_REPORTING',0);` in your wp-config.php. Note that this is not a permanent solution but might let you get into your wp-admin short-term.